# How do import "Counter" Values to csv

Tags: python

[Counter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElmRF.png)

I have a list of words and their frequencies in "Counter" file in Python.
I want to import them to my csv file so that I have

(1) words in the first column
(2) values in the second column

I tried

```
output_file.write(str(list_of_negwords)+';'+'\n')
```

But it is not stored in different rows but in columns and all broken..

[Excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9PGH.png)

Comment: Please edit the code in your question to be a [mre] including imports and some _minimal_ data to show the result you aren’t happy with. __Don’t__ show text as pictures - put that into your question as _text_

Comment: what do you have in `list_of_negwords` ? Show minimal working code with example data. If it is list of words then maybe you should use `for`-loop to write every word in seperated row. And then you can format every row separatelly. Or maybe better use module `csv` or `pandas` to create file

Answer (score 0):

Python has a [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library to not do it by hand :

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

words = Counter()
words["refrigerator"] = 4
words["rotation"] = 7

with open("so67730387.csv", "wt", newline="") as file:  # the newline here is important !
                                                        # cf https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=";")
    header = ("word", "count")
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(words.items())
```

gives me the file

```
word,count
refrigerator,4
rotation,7
```